# How long does it take to validate transactions?

Tags: transactions, validators

It seems to be a common sense that validation process on the blockchain is very fast. I wonder how fast the process could be? How long does it usually take to validate a transaction? What will be done to validate a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

There are different factors that affect the time to consider a transaction as validated.

- Gas price: the lower it is defined in the transaction, the more time to be picked up by miners. You can check that in [ETH Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info/).
- Network congestion: if there is a high number of transactions to be processed during a certain period, this will affect also the gas price (newer transactions might increase the gas price to go faster, so the rest will have to wait more).
- Number of block confirmations: the more you set, the more you wait, being 12 blocks as an overall *safe* value (this is to avoid potential forks or uncle (orphaned) blocks).

If the average time to mine a block is around 14 seconds (nowadays), then you can estimate the time to validate a transaction depending on the decisions you make on the above points.

Comment: I think validation is irrelevant to gas price, network congestion and number of block confirmations. When a node receives a new transaction, it needs to validate the transaction firstly(check the balance, the nonce, etc.). I just wonder how long it will take to do that. I think maybe it is related to cpu time. But I want to know an estimated time.

Comment: I think you are mixing the concept of mining vs. validated transaction. If you are only referring to the mining process by a node, it all depends on the hash power of that node (so there is no straight answer, because you can't compare a GPU at your home vs. a professional mining farm). A validated tx has a wider scope in which the conditions I mentioned influence in the time to consider a transaction as validated.